# ftp_nlist returning boolean true - not working on server, is on dev

Tags: php, ftp

I've written some code that accesses an FTP server and pulls down flat files. It works on my development environment in WAMP (Windows; 5.3.10) but on the production server (5.3.2 - Linux) it fails when calling ftp_nlist.

It sits there for about 30 seconds and then dies with the coded error message `[FTP] Unable to retrieve files in the directory`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
$link = ftp_connect(constant("FTP_SERVER"));
if(!$link)
    die("Unable to open connection to FTP Server: " + constant("FTP_SERVER"));

if(!ftp_login($link,
        constant("FTP_USER"),
        constant("FTP_PASSWORD")))
    die("Unable to login; check username and password.");

if(!ftp_chdir($link,
        constant("FTP_PATH")))
    die("Unable to change to directory: " + constant("FTP_PATH")); 

ftp_pasv($link, true);
clearDownloadDir();  // Delete already downloaded files

/* Get a list of all files */
$files = ftp_nlist($link, '.');
if(!$files)
    die("[FTP] Unable to retrieve files in the directory.");
```

The constants are defined in another file as:

```
define("FTP_SERVER", "ftp.{server}");
define("FTP_PATH", "./Australia/");
define("FTP_USER", "{user}");
define("FTP_PASSWORD", "{password}");
```

The thing that gets me is that it is connecting (evidenced by the fact its not dying on ftp_connect) and works locally. FTP_NLIST is returning boolean TRUE (1). Any ideas?

Comment: @MikePurcell yes - it works from my dev box.

Comment: @MikePurcell the code works unedited on my development box. The remote server is correctly configured and the authentication details are correct; my suspicion is it's something deeper.

Comment: Ok, I must have lost something in translation. You have code which you tested on dev, worked fine, then you published it to your production server, where the code does not work? If this is the case maybe ensure that your production server allows outbound connections.

Comment: @MikePurcell thanks, but the server is allowing the connection - it's not dying on ftp_connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the firewall on the shared server this code was running on was preventing FTP entering passive mode. Very odd.